# $X$ has exponential moment if $P(|X| > 2nC) \le e^t \alpha^n$ for $0\le \alpha < 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is some random variable and we have the inequality
$$P(|X| > 2nC) \le e^t \alpha^n$$ for some fixed $C>0$ and $\alpha \in [0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How do we conclude from this that $X$ has exponential moment and hence moments of all orders?

Comment: $Ee^{cX}=\int_0^{\infty} P(e^{cX} >t) dt=\int_0^{\infty} P(X >\frac {\ln t} c) dt$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why do we get $P(e^{cX} > t) = P(X> \frac{P}{ln t}c)$? And what is $P$ here? Also how do we use the bound for $P(|X|>2nC)$?